# D3 animation velocity control

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

I have write something using javascript animation skills,you can visit [Demonstration page](http://jsfiddle.net/jDeJ2/) for demonstration.

My question is how to make sure the circle moving in a constant velocity.Maybe it can called average velocity?

To meet the demand of stackoverflow,I should post some code as well to be available to post the question with link to jsfiddle!

```
function move(){
    for(var i = 0;i < Spot.length;++i){
        var time = randomGenerator(4000,8000);
        Spot[i].transition().duration(time)
            .attrTween("transform",translateAlong(d3.select("#path" + i).node(),i))
            .each("end",move);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want each movement to occur at a steady rate, you need to use a "linear" [ease function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-ease).  If you want to move all the shapes at the *same* velocity, the time (duration of the transition) has to be calculated as a function of the length of the path for each element (Time = length * 1/speed).

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thanks alot:),I sorry for my poor knowledge.